# Best modeling practices to keep time history of events in a graph database

Tags: database-design, graph

What are the best practices when modeling a **graph database** to keep track of the date and time when relationships change in order to be able, when needed, to rebuild any part of the sequence of events that led to the current graph ?

For example, let us assume the following :

- we want to model a social graph with users and "*is friends with*" relationships,
- "*is friends with*" relationships come and go over time,
- we can easily see that Bob is *currently* friends with Tom but we also want to know that :

  - Bob started being friends with Tom at date D1
  - then stopped being friends with Tom at date D2
  - then was friends again with Tom at date D3

In the absence of a better suggestion, I am considering doing the following :

- creating three types of relationships (assuming the second and third relationships are stored in the graph database with some kind of "created at" timestamp) :

  - "*is friends with*"
  - "*starts being friends with*"
  - "*stops being friends with*"
- maintaining consistency everytime an event occurs by both updating (i.e. creating or deleting) the "*is friends with*" relationship and creating a "*starts*" or "*stops being friends with*" relationship that adds to the potentially existing ones.

Comment: Your suggestion is spot on. Why do you think it's not good? It's exactly what graph databases handle really well and RDMS handle inefficiently.

Comment: @I.K. Thanks. I was just wondering if there were not a better way since (i) my suggestion assumes that two of the three relationships are timestamped (is it default case ? is it an option ?) and (ii) the information stored is redundant because the current state could be inferred by the last event (e.g. if last event is start/stop, then Bob is/is not friends with Tom), which could be bad practice...

Comment: Yes, I understand your concern about the redundancy of "is friends with" as it occurred to me as well. However, I then thought that it may be quicker to retrieve the current "friend" status with that relationship (in terms of query performance) than doing some date query. What I suggest is to experiment: time the query which references the "is friends with" relationship to get the current friendship status compared with using the other relationships. I don't think there is any best practice here. Rather, I think you take on the "best approach" to serve your problem domain. Hope it helps.

Comment: Good suggestion to time both approaches to compare them, @I.K. This will give objective data to manage the trade-off between performance and absence of data redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously different graph databases may have implementation differences. But my take would be:

Create an Edge "friends" with properties "started" and "stopped". Set stopped property only if the friendship ends. You can have multiple "friends" edges between people, if the relationship rekindles.

I am copy pasting from [Pixy Tutorial](https://github.com/lambdazen/pixy/wiki/Pixy-Tutorial) "Survivors and Parameters" section. I believe the example is very similar to your question. It uses Prolog to write parts of the query, a very brilliant idea in my opinion.

```
gremlin> pt = pt.extend(''' \
  livingAsOf(Person, Year) :- property(Person, 'born', Year1), Year1 =< Year, livingAsOfSub(Person, Year). \
  livingAsOfSub(Person, Year) :- property(Person, 'died', Year2), Year2 >= Year. \
  livingAsOfSub(Person, Year) :- not(property(Person, 'died', _)). \
''')

gremlin> g.V().as('p').pixy(pt, 'livingAsOf($, ?)', 1950) \
    .select(['p'], {it.name + ', born ' + it.born + (it.died ? ', died ' + it.died : '') })
```

Update 2014-08-22:
Regards to db specific implementation, with Cassandra backed Titan, it might make sense to store the "started" and "stopped" fields as a set and have a single friendship relationship edge. I would like to retract from the multiple friendship edges, as it may add unnecessary complexity, but certain databases and query patterns may perform better with that schema. With Titan-Cassandra, you may find that duplicating first started and last stopped cases as fields on their own and have another set field as I mentioned above, which would only exist for cases where friendships stopped and restarted. It depends upon your choice of database and what your query patterns will be. So testing is the way to go as you wrote in your comment.

Comment: Good suggestion, I like the idea of refactoring the "starts" and "stops" as properties into one single type of relationship ("friends") while keeping the entire friendship history. One question might remain about performance (i.e. how fast will it be to find friends of X, since the query will have a condition about the existence of a "stop" property). Testing will tell.

Comment: I added another paragraph at the end.

Comment: When speaking of "fields", "fields set" and "set field", do you mean edge properties ?

Comment: As a set like a list or an array, [] as in js speak.

Comment: Posted a bit too early, was that clearer? Cassandra has such a data type [built in](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html#collections). Hence it would be efficient to store in Titan-Cassandra, but query-wise it depends upon your pattern.